# Using custom field content as expression in IF statement

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field

I want to store some conditional logic in custom post types , and then use these in a plugin to generate new content based on the logic.

Eg if a user submits a form with “body temperature”, a conditional logic will tell the user if she has a fever or not, and some extra text.

There will be many such logic elements and I would like to maintain them from the front end.

I was thinking about putting the above into two posts. One with condition field “temperature > 37” and text “you have a fever”.
Then in a plugin loop through logic records, take the conditional field and use it as the expression in an if statement.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in another group and here I got an answer that has turned out to be useful.

BE AWARE! It must be dealt with with caution as the PHP eval() function can be a significant security risk.

Find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518496/11309498

Comment: Hi KCarter, please avoid crossposts. Since you found you answer there please make your answer here a real answer (not just link only) by quoting the answer and attributing the author of the answer..